# Unable to load class warning?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am making a sprite kit game and need to save three integers: currentLevel, maxLevelReached and highScore. I would also like to implement those to iCloud, but thats another step for me, first I want to figure out the problems I have right now. Basically, I am trying to use core data to store those. In my app delegate I added the following (basically I created new project and copied core data code)

```
    // MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1] as! NSURL
    }()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {

    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("GameState", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
    }()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("APPNAME.sqlite")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
        coordinator = nil
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
    }()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil {
        return nil
    }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
    }()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

when I did that, I created my data model (File->new->CoreData->Data model) and named it GameState. I then created the entity called CurrentLevel and added attribute of type Int16 and name currentLevel. I made the entity of class Appname.CurrentLevel. Then, in my game scene I added the following properties:

```
var currentLevel = [NSManagedObject]()
var levelToShow: Int16!
```

And created these two functions to handle core data stuff.

```
    //Handling the fetching from the CoreData
func fetchTheStuff() {

    //1
    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    //2
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"CurrentLevel")

    //3
    var error: NSError?

    let fetchedResults =
    managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest,
        error: &error) as? [NSManagedObject]

    if let results = fetchedResults {
        currentLevel = results
        println(currentLevel)
    } else {
        println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }

}


//Handling the saving

func saveCurrentLevel(cLevel: Int16){

    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("CurrentLevel",
        inManagedObjectContext:
        managedContext)

    let curLevel = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
        insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

    curLevel.setValue(name, forKey: "currentLevel")

    var error: NSError?
    if !managedContext.save(&error) {
        println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
    }

}
```

As you can see the fetch function is still in testing stage (I am simply printing the results). If I fetch it the first time I use the app, it gives me an empty string, as it should be. However, If I try to save a number using save function and then fetch the stuff, the log screen gives me the following warning:

CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'appname.CurrentLevel' for entity 'CurrentLevel'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.

Knowing the function I want to achieve, seeing the method I (try) to use, does anyone know how to solve my problem?

P.S. Also, it seems that this whole core data stuff is quite complicated, I have a hard time grasping how exactly it works even though I read a quite a lot about it. So if anyone has a suggestion on decreasing the complexity to achieve the same result (hence, not using any of the functionality) , tips are more than welcome.

Comment: did you properly generate the class files for the coredata model?

Comment: sorry, but could you please explain what you mean? I wish I knew.

Comment: in your coredata model. highlight the entities and chose Editor -> Create NSObject subclass. This requires a properly setup model that matches your code

Comment: ok, apparently that solves the problem with the warning. I would mark it as an answer, but I cant since its in the comment. Also, now I have a new problem - currentLevel = Nil. Any ideas on that?

Comment: I created an answer for future readers of your question. 
For further information, please provide more specific code or (better) open a new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to the initial question**
Please make sure, to generate the correct classes for your Coredata Model, highlighting your entities and then chosing *Editor -> Create NSObject* subclass